# How do we use sin,cos,tan generically (including user-defined types) in Python?

Tags: python, user-defined-types

*Edit: Let me try to reword and improve my question. The old version is attached at the bottom.*

What I am looking for is a way to express and use free functions in a type-generic way. Examples:

```
abs(x)  # maps to x.__abs__()
next(x) # maps to x.__next__() at least in Python 3
-x      # maps to x.__neg__()
```

In these cases the functions have been designed in a way that allows users with user-defined types to customize their behaviour by delegating the work to a non-static method call. This is nice. It allows us to write functions that don't really care about the exact parameter types as long as they "feel" like objects that model a certain concept.

Counter examples: Functions that can't be easily used generically:

```
math.exp  # only for reals
cmath.exp # takes complex numbers
```

Suppose, I want to write a generic function that applies exp on a list of number-like objects. What exp function should I use? How do I select the correct one?

```
def listexp(lst):
    return [math.exp(x) for x in lst]
```

Obviously, this won't work for lists of complex numbers even though there is an exp for complex numbers (in cmath). And it also won't work for any user-defined number-like type which might offer its own special exp function.

So, what I'm looking for is a way to deal with this on both sides -- ideally without special casing a lot of things. As a writer of some generic function that does not care about the exact types of parameters I want to use the correct mathematical functions that is specific to the types involved without having to deal with this explicitly. As a writer of a user-defined type, I would like to expose special mathematical functions that have been augmented to deal with additional data stored in those objects (similar to the imaginary part of complex numbers).

What is the preferred pattern/protocol/idiom for doing that? I did not yet test `numpy`. But I downloaded its source code. As far as I know, it offers a sin function for arrays. Unfortunately, I haven't found its implementation yet in the source code. But it would be interesting to see how they managed to pick the right sin function for the right type of numbers the array currently stores.

In C++ I would have relied on function overloading and ADL (argument-dependent lookup). With C++ being statically typed, it should come as no surprise that this (name lookup, overload resolution) is handled completely at compile-time. I suppose, I could emulate this at runtime with Python and the reflective tools Python has to offer. But I also know that trying to import a coding style into another language might be a bad idea and not very idiomatic in the new language. So, if you have a different idea for an approach, I'm all ears.

I guess, somewhere at some point I need to manually do some type-dependent dispatching in an extensible way. Maybe write a module "tgmath" (type generic math) that comes with support for real and complex support as well as allows others to register their types and special case functions... Opinions? What do the Python masters say about this?

TIA

Edit: Apparently, I'm not the only one who is interested in generic functions and type-dependent overloading. There is [PEP 3124](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3124/) but it is in draft state since 4 years ago.

---

*Old version of the question:*

I have a strong background in Java and C++ and just recently started learning Python. What I'm wondering about is: How do we extend mathematical functions (at least their names) so they work on other user-defined types? Do these kinds of functions offer any kind of extension point/hook I can leverage (similar to the iterator protocol where `next(obj)` actually delegates to `obj.__next__`, etc) ?

In C++ I would have simply overloaded the function with the new parameter type and have the compiler figure out which of the functions was meant using the argument expressions' static types. But since Python is a very dynamic language there is no such thing as overloading. What is the preferred Python way of doing this?

Also, when I write custom functions, I would like to avoid long chains of

```
if isinstance(arg,someClass):
    suchandsuch
elif ...
```

What are the patterns I could use to make the code look prettier and more Pythonish?

I guess, I'm basically trying to deal with the lack of function overloading in Python. At least in C++ overloading and argument-dependent lookup is an important part of good C++ style.

Is it possible to make

```
x = udt(something)  # object of user-defined type that represents a number
y = sin(x)          # how do I make this invoke custom type-specific code for sin?
t = abs(x)          # works because abs delegates to __abs__() which I defined.
```

work? I know I could make sin a non-static method of the class. But then I lose genericity because for every other kind of number-like object it's `sin(x)` and not `x.sin()`.

Adding a `__float__` method is not acceptable since I keep additional information in the object such as derivatives for "automatic differentiation".

TIA

Edit: If you're curious about what the code looks like, check [this](http://ideone.com/H6z60) out. In an ideal world I would be able to use sin/cos/sqrt in a type-generic way. I consider these functions part of the objects interface even if they are "free functions". In `__somefunction` I did not qualify the functions with `math.` nor `__main__.`. It just works because I manually fall back on `math.sin` (etc) in my custom functions via the decorator. But I consider this to be an ugly hack.

Comment: It doesn't look like the built-in math functions have any kind of extension point. For example, `sin(x)` could have tried to fall back on a method: `x.__sin__()` ... *sigh* ...

Comment: `sin()` isn't a builtin function, so it wouldn't really make sense for the data model of generic objects to support a `__sin__` method. In most cases, if it makes sense to call `math.sin()` on an object, it should also make sense to be able to call `float()` on it.

Comment: Python 3.2 begs to differ: `<built-in function sin>`

Comment: weird, my python3.2 says: `NameError: name 'sin' is not defined`

Comment: Note: What I was trying to do in Python turns out to be a piece of cake in Julia (also much faster). Thank you, Julia! Multiple dispatch and JIT compilation for the win!

Answer (score 5):

you can do this, but it works backwards.  you implement `__float__()` in your new type and then `sin()` will work with your class.

in other words, you don't adapt sine to work on other types; you adapt those types so that they work with sine.

this is better because it forces consistency.  if there is no obvious mapping from your object to a float then there probably isn't a reasonable interpretation of `sin()` for that type.

[sorry if i missed the "__float__ won't work" part earlier; perhaps you added that in response to this?  anyway, for convincing proof that what you want isn't possible, python has the cmath library to add `sin()` etc for complex numbers...]

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not acceptable in my case since I try to use this custom type to automatically track derivatives (automatic differentiation).

Comment: ah, sorry.  (random plug of some symbolic diffn code i wrote in python once - http://acooke.org/cute/Differenti0.html in case it's helpful; i know it's not the same thing...)

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I would prefer to use automatic differentiation. Symbolic differentiation is a bit over the top since I don't need to see any formulas -- just evaluated functions and derivatives at discrete points. ;-)

Comment: I don't see why that's a problem. `__float__()` should return a new float, not convert your object to a float. That way `sin()` doesn't have to destroy information.

Comment: @Clueless: Where I come from (statically typed languages) "conversion" just means that: to create something new of a different type -- usually without altering the original object. The loss is elsewhere. I do have my own sin function for this user-defined type which takes care of the extra data that is available in the object. The `__float__` suggestion is as pointless as ignoring the imaginary part of a complex number. No, I cannot implement `__float__` in a way so that makes sense for the same reason it doesn't make sense to write float(some_complex_number)

Answer (score 4):

If you want the return type of `math.sin()` to be your user-defined type, you appear to be out of luck. Python's `math` library is basically a thin wrapper around a fast native IEEE 754 floating point math library. If you want to be internally consistent and duck-typed, you can at least put the extensibility shim that python is missing into your own code.

```
def sin(x):
    try:
        return x.__sin__()
    except AttributeError:
        return math.sin(x)
```

Now you can import this `sin` function and use it indiscriminately wherever you used `math.sin` previously. It's not quite as pretty as having `math.sin` pick up your duck-typing automatically but at least it can be consistent within your codebase.

Comment: Interesting. How would you add support for complex numbers here?

Comment: To be consistent you could have the class that implements complex numbers implement `__sin__()`. I think the fact is that this sort of polymorphism is nice as a core language feature for the most common operations, but these mathematical operations are so performance-intensive that people are willing to specify types explicitly. I think it's totally reasonable as the author of a mathematical library to say "We have made all of the builtin functions work with our derivative type, and anything else you need to import and use explicitly."

Answer (score 1):

Define your own versions in a module. This is what's done in cmath for complex number and in numpy for arrays.

Comment: Currently, this is what I do. Thank you for the numpy reference, though. I wonder how, for example, numpy's sin function delegates the work. It somehow has to find the correct sin function to apply it element-wise to arrays.

Comment: Also what's done for the decimal module for some operations (e.g. sqrt)

Answer (score 0):

Typically the answer to questions like this is "you don't" or "use duck typing".  Can you provide a little more detail about what you want to do?  Have you looked at the remainder of the protocol methods for numeric types?

http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you will derive your user-defined numeric types from a native Python type, and the math functions will just work. When that isn't possible, perhaps you can define `__int__()` or `__float__()` or `__complex__()` or `__long__()` on the object so it knows how to convert itself to a type the math functions can handle.

When *that* isn't feasible, for example if you wish to take a `sin()` of an object that stores x and y displacement rather than an angle, you will need to provide either your own equivalents of such functions (usually as a method of the class) or a function such as `to_angle()` to convert the object's internal representation to the one needed by Python.

Finally, it *is* possible to provide your own `math` module that replaces the built-in math functions with your own varieties, so if you want to allow math on your classes without any syntax changes to the expressions, it can be done in that fashion, although it is tricky and can reduce performance, since you'll be doing (e.g.) a fair bit of preprocessing in Python before calling the native implementations.

Comment: Umm, Python *does* support `__int__()` and `__float()__`, and the math functions *do* work fine...

Comment: Ugh. Google failed me badly on that. I thought I remembered that being the case, but couldn't find evidence of it. Edited my answer to reflect this.